# Using setTimeout func. & random func. to animate class elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-animate, settimeout

My debugging skills are not helping me much with figuring out what I am doing wrong here.

I want each element in an array to animate after a specified time using setTimeout function.

I am not getting any errors and the loop appears to run just fine, however, none of the elements in the array end up moving from their original place to the new spot.

```
function publicity()
{
// placing elements with class name 'cCameras' inside an array
var eCamerasArray = $(".cCameras").toArray();
// creating 2 arrays to hold left & top values of each element
var iLeftPosArray = [];
var iTopPosArray = [];
// loop to run through each element in array
for( var i = 0; i < eCamerasArray.length; i++)
{
    // timer variable set for each element to be used in setTimeout func.
    var timer = Math.floor (Math.random()*300) + 100;
    // setTimeout func. used to animate each element after a specified (timer) time
    window.setTimeout (function ()
    {
        iLeftPosArray[i] = Math.floor (Math.random() *139) + 360;
        iTopPosArray[i] = Math.floor (Math.random() *160) + 100 ;
        $(eCamerasArray[i]).animate ({left: iLeftPosArray[i] + "px", top: iTopPosArray[i] + "px"}, 100, "linear");
        return [iLeftPosArray[i], iTopPosArray[i]];
    }, timer);
}
}
```

Comment: javascript doesn't have block level scope, so all functions will refer to the same `i`.. someone find a duplicate on this :p

Comment: @Esailija, you totally lost me, would you please elaborate.

Comment: @Esailija - He's using it in an array, I don't think he would have that problem with this code. Kayote, start debugging by confirming the value of `eCamerasArray`, and then the resulting value of `iLeftPosArray` and `iTopPosArray` after the loop.

Comment: @KevinB ? The loop executes immediately, and the `i` will be same value for all the functions created once the timeouts start firing. There are at least 10 questions per day on this.

Comment: @KevinB, did. Firebug actually runs rather strangely through the function but does run through it all, including outputting the arrays correct content via console.log. iLeftPosArray & iTopPosArray also give the correct values.

Comment: @Esailija, Sorry, i missed the fact that he was using a `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it with creating closure:

```
(function publicity() {
    var eCamerasArray = $(".cCameras"),
        iLeftPosArray = [],
        iTopPosArray = [],
        timer;
    for(var i = 0; i < eCamerasArray.length; i += 1) {
        timer = Math.floor (Math.random() * 300) + 100;
        (function (i) {
            window.setTimeout (function () {
                iLeftPosArray[i] = Math.floor (Math.random() * 139) + 360;
                iTopPosArray[i] = Math.floor (Math.random() * 160) + 100 ;
                $(eCamerasArray[i]).animate ({left: iLeftPosArray[i] + "px", top: iTopPosArray[i] + "px"}, 300, "linear");
                return [iLeftPosArray[i], iTopPosArray[i]];
            }, timer);
        }(i));
    }
}());
```

You can see the effect here: http://jsfiddle.net/zHUAt/2/

Best regards!

Comment: thanks. I've read a few posts but never got the hang of closures.

Here is what my understanding is from your answer: The function for the setTimeout accepts the  'i' parameter to keep track of what loop no. is currently running. 

However, Im a bit lost of the last bit, at the end of the function where you have '}(i));, bottom third line. Why is 'i' being multiplied here?

Comment: You can think of it like the current state of i is saving inside the function body. So in the end you will not call the timeout function with i equals to 3.

Comment: Actually this (function () { //... }()) is a syntax for self executing function. In the example the function is anonymous and it accepts just a single parameter (that's i but not the same i like in the loop it could be with different value). I'm using '}(i));' because I want to pass i as a parameter to the self executing anonymous function. That's how it's "saving" into it's body the current value of i. I hope that I was clear :-). Best regards!

Comment: thank you so much for taking out the time for this. Ive been thinking and thinking but struggling a bit with this.

So in a nutshell, the 'i' inside the function (i) is different to the i above in the loop. However the (i) multiplication is the same 'i' as in the loop... 

First que, so this anonymous function is independent to the rest of the code in the parent function, except for the multiplication (i) at the end of it.

Surely multiplying a function with (i) shouldn't work as you are multiplying a method with a number...

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the function could be re-written as:
(function (y, i) {... }?
Here the 'y' parameter is the functions own internal counter but the 'i' is the parameter from the loop above?

Comment: @Kayote - No, but you could use `(function(y){...})(i)` to get that effect

Answer (score 1):

Unrolling a simple loop you can see what happens:

```
var i = 0;

window.setTimeout( function(){
      //No local i so it must be outside
    console.log(i);

}, 1000 );

i++;

window.setTimeout( function(){
     //No local i so it must be outside
    console.log(i);

}, 1000 );

i++;

window.setTimeout( function(){
      //No local i so it must be outside
    console.log(i);

}, 1000 );
```

As you can see, all the functions refer to the same `i`, so
they will all log `2` once the timers fire. None of them
have a local `i`.

You can create a "local" `i` like this:

```
(function(i){
|---------^  //i found here, no need to use the global i
|   window.setTimeout( function(){
-------------------- //no local i here so it must be outside
        console.log(i);

    }, 1000 );  


})(i) //pass the "global" i as argument, with the value it has right now
```

Comment: Ummm that's my solution, isn't it?

Comment: @mgechev that's anyone's solution, this question has millions of duplicates in slightly different forms. I was just trying to explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: This is a wonderful explanation. Thank you for clarifying this for me @Esailija.